# Multiple IF-statements in a single cell - checking long list of results

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a Google Sheets where I enter all the results of my beer pong matches with friends.
I'd like to see my amount of wins/losses with certain friends. This can be done with

`=IF(AND(B2="Won",E2="Stefan",1,0)`

Above code adds one point to a cell if I won with the teammate - adds 0 if not.
However, so far I have 25 recorded matches, and the list will keep getting new rows. I don't want a column that calculates wins and losses, because I'd like to be able to see my score with up to 10 different people - it'd be too many columns. I'd much rather have the amount of wins and losses in 2 singular cells. I could write the above code into a single cell for each row, but that'd take too much time. I need something similar to:

`=IF(AND(B2:B25="Won",E2:E25="Stefan",1,0)`

But this above code checks if ALL the rows are equal to "Won" or "stefan". I need it to check the if statement for each row, and then add 1 point for each row that resulted in `TRUE`.

Anyone knows what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `arrayformula` with a `sum` like this :

`=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(B2:B25="Won",E2:E25="Stefan",1,0)))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different formula to do that altogether.

Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B,"Won",E2:E, "Stefan")
```

If you create a pull down menu, with the names, then you'll be able to make the last argument in the `COUNTIFS` formula variable.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for - much simpler than I thought it'd be!
I do have a follow up question though. I have a column with opponents, however the rows include 2 names separated by commas, for example:
Stefan, Katrine
Would I be able to write something similar to the "COUNTIFS" that returns a TRUE if the rows have either Stefan or Katrine included?

Comment: Try this: =COUNTIFS(B2:B, "Won", ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E,"Stefan")), "Stefan")